# append one dataframe over another dynamically in R

Tags: r, rbind

I am having dataframe (dataframexml) which have 3 cols- Name, Path and URL and mutiple rows.Based on the URL, I am parsing the XML in R and creating a dataframe using getdataframe() function.So, based on the number of URLs, that many dataframes will be generated. (All the dataframes have same columns)

Now I need to add a new column to each dataframe which will have dataframe name in all rows and append one dataframe over another dynamically a create the master dataframe.
This is part where I am stuck. Looking for some guidance.

## Code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframexml)){

dataURL<- dataframexml[i,3]

dataURL.response<-GET(dataURL,authenticate("string","xxxxx"))

assign(paste("df",substr(dataframexml[i,3],85,100),sep=""),
getdataframe(dataURL.response))
# getdataframe() = A function to create dataframe from the URL

# parts stuck 
# "1st <- create a new column which will have dataframe name in all rows"
# "2nd" <- append one dataframe over another and create a master dataframe 

print(paste("df",substr(dataframexml[i,3],85,100),sep=""))
# For Testing
}
```

Comment: In the long run, it's probably most useful to use a version of `lapply`/`Map` and keep the resulting data.frames in a list.

Comment: Does using lapply/Map will help to improve the performance as compare to loops as sometime I need to run thousands of Urls

Comment: It does better than an unpreallocated `for` loop, but given you won't really know how much memory you need in this scenario, there's not really a way to avoid the slowness. The advantage is really afterwards, when you have a list of thousands of objects which you can easily iterate across instead of thousands of unconnected objects in your global environment. [Here's a longer explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050)

Comment: Also, `purrr::map2_df` might solve all your problems here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that in a loop. Basically, you create an empty object before your loop, which will be used to store the result. Then, in the loop, use `cbind` to add the name and finally `rbind` to add all the results on top of another.

```
dataframexml <- data.frame(name=c("a","b"),url=c("http1","http2"))

res <- NULL #create empty object
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframexml)){

name_loop <- dataframexml[i,"name"]
getdataframe_result <- data.frame(col1=runif(2),col2=runif(2))
getdataframe_result_with_name <- cbind(name_loop,getdataframe_result)
res <- rbind(res,getdataframe_result_with_name)
}

> res
  name_loop     col1      col2
1         a 0.267059 0.4765398
2         a 0.730072 0.4079391
3         b 0.131630 0.7102743
4         b 0.678059 0.0624137
```

Comment: Added this line in my code: getdataframe_result$newcol <- substr(dataframexml[i,3],85,100) to suffice my need of having col in the dataframe generated. And hope u mean cbind to add the name and finally rbind to add all the results on top of another :)

Comment: @string Yes, I switched them around. I edited my answer.